# Is it possible have Flyout menu over MapControl on UWP application?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Is it any idea to create menu over MapControl on UWP like below image ?

[image: sample map menu]

Comment: Can you show where have you encountered problems and what have you tried? As for direct answer - yes it's possible. Currently your question is way too broad.

Comment: I tried to use Flyout but can't set the correct position of Flyout content on the left and top of screen.

Comment: I didn't want use menu or hamburger menu , because this menu is conditional on when a user click on custom button on map

Comment: in simple description , i have grid in page and i want to show this grid over MapControl conditionally.

Comment: @MahdiSheikhi Just put that grid below your `MapControl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. According to your comments, one way may be to put dummy UIElement under the map (with suitable menu) and show it when needed. XAML:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Border x:Name="SamapleBorder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Border.ContextFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 1"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 2"/>
                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Item 3"/>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </Border.ContextFlyout>
    </Border>
    <Rectangle Fill="Beige" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="Rectangle_Tapped"/>
</Grid>
```

and the code behind:

```cs
private void Rectangle_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) => this.SamapleBorder.ContextFlyout.ShowAt(this.SamapleBorder);
```

[image: MenuOverRectangle]